# How to save the data from file into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

So here's the new Code: 
code is print weird text instead of numbers but calculates the median and average correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Array {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    File myFile = new File("numbers.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    int[] mynumFile = new int[4];
    int i = 0;
    double median;
    double sum = 0;
    int middle;

    while (inputFile.hasNextInt())
    {

        mynumFile[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
        sum += mynumFile[i];
        i++;          


        System.out.println(numFile);

        /*and if i do -->  System.out.println(mynumFile); 
                     it prints [I@55f96302, [I@55f96302, [I@55f96302,      [I@55f96302 and i dont know 
                     what this is, since the program does not throw any errors or exceptions */


    }

    middle = (mynumFile.length)/2;

    median = (mynumFile[middle-1] + mynumFile[middle]) / 2.0;

    System.out.println("Median number is: " + median);
    System.out.println("Average of the numbers is: " + sum/mynumFile.length);



    inputFile.close();



}
```

}

So I want to write a Java program to read in all of the numbers in the file into an array. Then find the median of the numbers and print it out to the console. The median should be of type double.  The median of a list of even numbers is the average of the middle two numbers, for example assume the median is ((NUMBER_2+NUMBER_3) / 2). I also want to find the average of the numbers in the array.

My problem is I don't get how to read in all of the values from the file into an array. my code prints out the number from my file to the console just fine but how to read it into an array and then do the calculations?

This is a test program, so my file has 4 single digit numbers such as 5, 7, 9, 4

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Array {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        File myFile = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

        int[] mynumFile = new int[4];
        int i = 0;

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            int numFile = inputFile.nextInt();

            System.out.println(numFile);
        }

        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And whats with the vote down????

Answer (score 3):

You can use an ArrayList to create an array without knowing the number of elements you will read from the file (that I suspect is the case).

This would read all the integers from the File to an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numFile = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    numFile.add(inputFile.nextInt());
}
```

To get all the integers you can do the same but using a foreach loop.

```
for(int i : numFile)
{
  // use your number (i) here
}
```

If you really want to use an array, you could use your variable i as an index. However, if you have more integers on the file than you array can accomodate, you would get an exception.

```
int i = 0;
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    try{
        mynumFile[i++] = inputFile.
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        // more integers than you array can hold
        // handle this situation here
    }
}
```

As mentioned, this will throw an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) if you don't have enough space for al your integers.

**EDIT:**
As Bruno Toffolo commented, we can [try](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) to access the i position on the array and handle that exception (if it happens) on a [catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block. This will avoid the exception to be propagated through your methods, which can end up terminating your program.

**EDIT 2:**
The problem is that `System.out.println(numFile);` will print information about your ArrayList (numFile). If you want to print an element of the ArrayList you should use the `get(i)` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)). This method will retrieve the integer on position i of the ArrayList. i.e. `System.out.println(numFile.get(2));`

Comment: In the final approach, it would be good to enclose it in a try/catch statement to avoid propagating the possible exception.

Comment: Good point. I edited the code and added the try/catch statement.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Java, learning on my own and this is my second  month so i'm not sure/know much about try/catch. what is its purpose?